# if I update the metadata "description" on iTunes Connect, will it be visible prior to next app version release/

Tags: app-store-connect

if I update the metadata "description" for a deployed iPhone app on iTunes Connect, will users see this when searching the app store prior to the next app release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (seems it needed a delay before it come out)